# background image not applying to css grid

Tags: html, css, flask

I'm trying to set background images in grids nested inside my main grid but they're not showing.  My css files are located in static/css and my images are located in static/img.  This is my main problem.

The other question I have is how do I center the .container grid in the middle of the page?

this is my main css file

```
@import "sidebar.css";

body{
    margin: 0px;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1306;
    margin: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: 286px 3000px;
    grid-template-columns: 2px 250px 2px 1050px 2px;
    grid-template-areas: "banner banner banner banner banner"
                            "left sidebar middle content right"

}

#bannergrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-area: banner;
    background-image: url(../img/banner.png);
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns:  auto 125px;
    grid-template-rows: 30px auto;
    grid-template-areas: "topleft topright"
                            "bottom bottom";
    margin: 0px;
    
}

#login{
    grid-area: topright;
}

#topleft{
    grid-area: topleft;
}

#bottom{
    grid-area: bottom;
}

#left{
    grid-area: left;
    background-color: #153958;
}

#middle{
    grid-area: middle;
    background-color: #153958;
}

#right{
    grid-area: right;
    background-color: #153958;
}

#content{
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    grid-area: content;
}

#sidebargrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-image: url(../img/sidebar.png);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px auto;
    grid-template-areas: "rules"
                            "games"
                            "stories"
                            "heroes"
                            "npcs"
                            "locations"
                            "skills"
                            "abilities"
                            "powers"
                            "flaws"
                            "equipment"
                            "devices"
                            "armor"
                            "weapons"
                            "vehicles"
                            "constructs"

}

.btn-login{
    width: 125px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #af0101;
    font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.btn-login:hover {
    width: 125px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-color: white;
    background-color: #3a4e87;
    font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

and this is the template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="{{ meta_name }}" content="{{ meta_content }}" />

        <title>{{ title }}</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        {% for style in stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ style.style }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        {% endfor %}

    </head>

    <body>
        <c>
        <div class="container">

            <div id="bannergrid">
                <div id="topleft"></div>
                <div id="login">
                    <div class="btn-login"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="bottom"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="left"></div>

            <div id="sidebargrid">
            <div id="rules">
                <div class="button">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="games">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/gamesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/gamesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/gamesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="stories">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/storiesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/storiesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/storiesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="heroes">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/heroesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/heroesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/heroesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="npcs">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/npcsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/npcsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/npcsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="locations">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/locationsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/locationsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/locationsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="skills">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/skillsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/skillsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/skillsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="abilities">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/abilitiesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/abilitiesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/abilitiesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="powers">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/powersGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/powersBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/powersGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="flaws">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/flawsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/flawsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/flawsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="equipment">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/equipmentGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/equipmentBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/equipmentGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="devices">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/devicesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/devicesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/devicesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="armor">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/armorGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/armorBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/armorGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="weapons">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/weaponsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/weaponsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/weaponsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="vehicles">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/vehiclesGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/vehiclesBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/vehiclesGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="constructs">
                <div class="button">
                    <img src="/static/img/sidebar/constructsGOLD.png" 
                    onmouseover="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/constructsBLUE.png'" 
                    onmouseout="this.src='/static/img/sidebar/constructsGOLD.png'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div id="middle"></div>
            <div id="content">
                {% include includehtml %}
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
        </c>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a directory structure?

Comment: https://github.com/mikewycklendt/dcadventures

Comment: its the grid background images that aren't showing

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I set the background on the div in the html template